# MVC routing not working C# backend React frontend

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, api, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC with .Net. I have a C# controller as follows:

```
namespace TFL.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TubeApiController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetTubeStatus()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.tfl.gov.uk");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync("/Line/Mode/tube/Status");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(stringResult);

                        return Ok(new
                        {
                            LineId = rawData[0].name
                        });

                }
                catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {
                    return BadRequest("Error getting data");
                }
            }
        }

    }


    public class RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<LineStatus> lineStatuses { get; set; }

    }

    public class LineStatus
    {
        public string statusSeverityDescription { get; set; }

    }

}
```

and I want to get this data to display on the front end:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";


export class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lineId: "",
            status: ""
        };
    }

    getData(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch("api/tubeapi/gettubestatus")
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(text => console.log(text))

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <center>
                    <h1>Tube</h1>
                    <h4>Name</h4>
                    <p>{this.state.lineId}</p>
                    <h4>Status</h4>
                    <p>{this.state.status}</p>

                </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

When I visit localhost:5000/api/tubeapi/gettubestatus I get the Json I am expecting: `{lineId: "Bakerloo" }`(which is all I need to practice with for now) but with the code I have written it is not fetching this data. I am trying to debug it by console logging out the text that the fetch is getting but nothing appears in the console whatsoever. Does anyone have any suggestions for where I'm going wrong? Thanks

**Edit: my package.json file for one of the comments: **

```
{
  "name": "tfl",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "merge": "^1.2.1",
    "oidc-client": "^1.9.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.9.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rimraf ./build && react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: are you doing the proxy in your package.json ? so let me conclude your backend .net is running in 5000 and you are running your react in 3000 am i correct, please add your package.json of react application.

Comment: Sorry @DILEEPTHOMAS I don't quite understand. I'll edit my answer to show my package.json

Comment: you dont have the proxy, so when u call the api , api/tubeapi/gettubestatus you are not adding http://localhost:5000/api/tubeapi/gettubestatus because your server runs in that port

Comment: Thanks @DILEEPTHOMAS - how can I fix this?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS even when I change the api call to "https://localhost:5000/api/tubeapi/gettubestatus" it still does not work?

Comment: Give me a minute i will add the answer, Happy to help, if the answer helped you kindly upvote and accept it so the future people can refer easily

Comment: did you added http

Comment: kindly check the answer

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is basically you are not mentioning the absolute url, you are using relative url. In that case you need to tell which port is m back end is running.

As your .net application server is running in 5000 you need point it out in package.json on react application in order to use the relative url

so in your package.json add below browser list and restart your app. Because if you do any changes in package.json you need to restart then only the new changes will be reflected

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

and in the code `fetch("api/tubeapi/gettubestatus")` use and check, hopefully you will be able to see the response.

Comment: Thanks @DILEEPTHOMAS but I am not sure this is the problem. I added that line under browser list and amended the fetch request, restarted the app and still have nothing in the console :(

Comment: when you try to hit http://localhost:5000/api/tubeapi/gettubestatus in chrome are you getting response

Comment: Yes @DILEEPTHOMAS I get: `{lineId: "Bakerloo"}` which is what I expect to see

Comment: Then this should work did you restarted the react application

Comment: Yes I did :( @DILEEPTHOMAS